# React: How to present array of objects using map() function

Tags: reactjs

I have spring boot app for "backend" in order to retrieve data for stocks from yahoo.finance. I have tested the app with postman and retrieves the data. However, I can't make the React ui to present them and the error that I get is 'TypeError: stocks.map is not a function
'. My React class:

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const StockPage = () => {

    const [stocks, setStocks] = useState({});

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const fetchStockData = async () => {
                const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/stock/AAPL/2021-06-07/2021-06-11");
                const stockData = await response.json();
                setStocks(stockData)
                console.log(stockData);
            };
            fetchStockData();
        },[]
    );

  return (
    <div className="StockPage">
        <h2>Stock Data</h2>
        <div className="header-section">
            {stocks.map(stock => <p>{stock.date} {stock.open} {stock.high} {stock.low} {stock.close} {stock.adjClose} {stock.volume}</p>)}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, the console.log(stockData) prints out the array of stock object in browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your state initialization.

```
const [stocks, setStocks] = useState({});
```

You're setting the initial state to an object, not an array. You need

```
const [stocks, setStocks] = useState([]);
```

assuming that the API will give you an array in response.